# Accessing of file from other system in Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill

I am using latest version of drill i.e (1.5 version) and using drill in embedded mode for local.
  I have some csv file in my other system(PC2), which has some I.P address. I want to run search query from my own system(PC1) and try to get that csv file which is store in other system(PC2). PC1 have Drill and its running throught cmd in embedded mode.

> Is There any way to get data or to search files(csv, psv, etc) from other pc(remote machine) in embedded mode for local(not for hdfs)?

Comment: **Don't ask so generic questions you will not get answers but only get downvotes.** For example, here you did not mention Drill version, mode(_embedded or distributed_), OS, file system(_local or hdfs or something else_). Always share relevant details in the question & try to format your question well. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could try to mount drive from remote pc as local drive, and then run your drill queries on local drive. I did that with linux PC.
But this is not best decision for querying big files. Better to setup drill in distributed mode and run drillbit on machine where you store your data.

Comment: ok I will try to  setup my drill in distributed mode and try to access from remote server.